# heroku django tutorial not working?

Tags: django, heroku

I'm trying to work through the "Getting Started with Django" heroku tutorial. Things are working when I run the framework locally with foreman, but when I try to run it on Heroku, it is failing when trying to find the settings module.

In a nutshell, I've done...

```
chris@xi:~: mkdir hero
chris@xi:~: cd hero
chris@xi:~/hero: django-startproject ku .
```

and then I create and edit the files per the instructions. Perhaps I have gotten something wrong?

in ~/hero, I created my Procfile and requirements.txt, as well as the ku directory that was created by django-admin

in ~/hero/ku I have settings.py and wsgi.py (created by django-admin and edited by me)

any idea what I'm not doing correctly?

Answer (score 0):

found it after much trial end error.  It turns out that I had an old .gitignore file in my home directory that ignored settings.py.  Once I added settings.py to the project and re-pushed, everything started working.

I don't like putting settings.py into git because it contains machine-specific information, as well as security information.  But I guess I will leave it for now, and when I have to do it for real, I can use the `heroku config:set` command to set up things like database users and passwords, or paths to DJANGO_SETTINGS_FILE, etc.